# Registry is setting 1 char

Tags: c++, windows, registry

My code is setting 1 char of the registry name and value.

```
bool setRegValue(std::wstring valueName, std::wstring  valueToSet)
{
    HKEY key=NULL;
    if (get_HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE(&key) && (key!=NULL))
    {

        if (RegSetValueEx((HKEY)key, (LPCSTR)valueName.c_str(), 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)valueToSet.c_str(), (valueToSet.size() +1)*sizeof(wchar_t)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            RegCloseKey((HKEY)key);
            log.error("Failed to SET the registry value. Name : "+ std::string(valueName.begin(), valueName.end())+" Value : "+ std::string(valueToSet.begin(), valueToSet.end()));
            RegCloseKey(key);
            return false;
        }
        log.info("Successfully SET the registry value. Name : " + std::string(valueName.begin(), valueName.end()) + " Value : " + std::string(valueToSet.begin(), valueToSet.end()));
        RegCloseKey(key);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And, this is the calling method.

```
bool setServiceAsClient()
{ 
    if (setRegValue(L"ServiceType", L"Client"))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Its setting the registry name as `S`
And, value as `C`

Comment: And what is your question? Does it not work? In what way does it not work? Do you get an error message and/or error code?

Comment: Are we supposed to find right question for this answer?

Comment: What is `get_HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`? The `key` for `RegSetValueEx` should be _A handle to an open registry key._, which would typically be something like `HKLM\SOFTWARE\[Company]\blahblahblah` The function name implies it is `HKLM` itself... Copy and pasted, this is what I use (not Unicode, so using `A` version) `val = RegSetValueEx( hKey, strValueName.c_str(), 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE *)strValue.c_str(), (DWORD)strValue.size() + 1 );` Yours looks basically identical, but modified for Unicode, so not seeing anything off the top.

Comment: Same underlying cause as [wsprintfW printing only tens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749241/wsprintfw-printing-only-tens). The cast is always suspicious. I suspect you got a compiler warning about a type mismatch, but instead of addressing the mismatch, you just used a cast to say "Trust me."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a wide-char string is seen as a 1-char string, that's a symptom that you're providing a wide-char string where a multi-byte string is expected.

Indeed we see the error here: `(LPCSTR)valueName.c_str()` (where `valueName` is a `std::wstring`).

`LPCSTR` is **`const char *`**, whereas [`wstring::c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) returns **`const wchar_t *`**.

So `L"ServiceType"` is seen as `"S\0e\0r\0v\0i\0c\0e\0T\0y\0p\0e\0"`, which becomes simply `"S"`

There are 2 solutions possible:

1. Use `std::string` instead of `std::wstring` (and remove the `L` from strings like `L"ServiceType"`). This solution is not recommended, since the Win32 API internally is Unicode.
2. Change project settings from **Multi-byte** to **Unicode Character Set** and remove the casting to `LPCSTR` (if you do need to cast, use `LPTSTR` instead, which always matches project character set settings).

See [Working with Strings - Win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more details.

Comment: A 3rd option that's commonly used is to use the wide-character or multibyte function name directly (e.g. `RegSetValueExW` and `RegSetValueExA`), and forget about the `TCHAR` macros.  It's unlikely that a program is going to be distributed as separate wide-character and multibyte versions. The choice is framed by required libraries and cross-platform requirements. In Windows 10, the multibyte API can be Unicode (UTF-8), but some functions are still only in the wide-character API, both with a "W" suffix (e.g. `GetVolumeInformationByHandleW`) and without it (e.g. `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the detail explanation @rustyx